# Recommended Syntax for HTML meta title and description?

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags, meta

I've been told that adding a different meta title and description per page is strongly recommended.

What is the correct way to do this? Is there a recommended naming convention for the title? I assume there's a standard for this rather than whatever the developer decides is best.

Comment: it's absolutely up to you. Just be careful bcs Google doesn't like when you put tons of keywords in the description. Be modest.

Comment: It's up to you. SEO works a lot differently today than it did 5 years ago. Google doesn't care much about your description, keywords, etc much anymore. It's more about the content and media of your pages.

Comment: I think that's okay. Descriptions should be unique, but adding some " :: MyBlog.com" part to the title is fine, everyone does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `title`

(Note that the `title` element is not a "meta title".)

HTML5 defines that the [`title` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) should identify documents "even when they are used out of context". So for a typical website, you should always include the site name in the title.

For usability reasons, it’s most of the time a [good idea](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/59858/17633) to specify the page name *before* the site name (e.g., `page name – site name`).

HTML5 doesn’t recommend a delimiter for separating the page name from the title.

#### `meta`-`description`

HTML5 defines that the [`description` metadata name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-description) is used to "describe the page". The value must be "appropriate for use in a directory of pages, e.g. in a search engine".

As the homepage typically represents the whole site, it’s appropriate to describe the site (instead of the page) in the homepage’s `meta`-`description`.

Comment: @user3420034: Yes,  `|` is used often and I don’t think there are any problems with using it (i.e., no misunderstandings/conflicts). -- Regarding `property="og:title"`: this is RDFa, probably using the [Open Graph vocabulary](http://ogp.me/). You’d have to consult the documentation of the vocabulary to see which value they expect for their `title` property,

Answer (score 1):

At first I would recommend to sign in to the [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/intl/en_en/webmasters/). There you sign in your website and get a lot of information and resources to improve the information structure of your website.

Here you have an article from Google about the topic: [Meta tags that Google understands](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)

About the `meta name="description"` element:

> `<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />`
>
> This tag provides a short description of the page. In some situations this description is used as a part of the snippet shown in the search results.

About the `title` element:

> `<title>The Title of the Page</title>`
>
> While technically not a meta tag, this tag is often used together with the "description". The contents of this tag are generally shown as the title in search results (and of course in the user's browser).

Also think about implementing [structured data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en), see [schema.org](http://schema.org/).

I think it is important these days to have a web standards based, clean and semantically rich HTML markup for your whole page.